# (scikit-image) HOG visualization image appears black when saved

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am new to computer vision and image processing and am using this code

```
from skimage.feature import hog
hog_list, hog_img = hog(test_img_gray, 
                        orientations=8, 
                        pixels_per_cell=(16, 16), cells_per_block=(1, 1),
                        block_norm='L1', 
                        visualise=True,
                        feature_vector=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.imshow(hog_img)
```

to get this HOG visualization image

[image]

I have 2 questions at this point:

1. When I try to save this image (as a .pdf or .jpg) the resulting image is pure black. Converting this image to PIL format and examining it with

   `hog_img_pil = Image.fromarray(hog_img)
   hog_img_pil.show()`

still shows the image as pure black. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

2. When I try to run this code

   `hog_img = cv2.cvtColor(hog_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

to convert the image to grayscale I get the error `error: (-215) depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F in function cvtColor`. What do I need to do to get this image in grayscale and why would this be happening?

As additional information, running `hog_img.shape` returns `(1632, 1224)` which is just the size of the image, which I had initially interpreted to mean that the image is already is already in grayscale (since it appears to be lacking a dimension for color channel). However, when I then tried to run

```
test_img_bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
    src=hog_img, 
    maxValue=255, 
    adaptiveMethod=cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
    thresholdType=cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 
    blockSize=115, C=4)
```

I got the error `error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function adaptiveThreshold` which [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478928/8236733) answer seems to indicate means that the image is not in grayscale.

Finally, another bit of useful information is that running `print(hog_img.dtype)` on the image returns `float64`.

I will continue to debug, in the meantime

Thanks for any thoughts :)

Comment: it's pretty obvious that all your problems are caused by having the wrong datatype. you have to convert your data from float64 to something the algorithms can handle. refer to the reference documentations and the assertion errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Inverting the image with `hog_img_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(hog_img)` and using 
   `plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
   plt.imshow(hog_img_uint8_inv)`
    
   showed that the lines were in fact there but are very faint (I've included the image here for comletness, but you can barley see it (but trust me, it's there)). I will have to do some more processing of the image to get the lines more distinguishable. 
   [image]
2. Running `print(hog_img.dtype)` showed that the dtype was `float64` when (I think) it should have been `uint8`. I fixed this by running `hog_img_uint8 = hog_img.astype(np.uint8)` which seems to have fixed the problem with passing the image to other algorithms (eg. cv2.adaptiveThreshold).

Answer (score 0):

If had the same problem. But if you look inside the [docu](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html), they also use this code for better visualisation:

```
# Rescale histogram for better display
hog_image_rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(hog_image, in_range=(0, 0.02))
```

But I still have the same problem. Visualisation with matplotlib is no problem. saving the image with opencv (or skimage) saves only a black image...